# I created a TF-IDF code to analyze an annual report, I want to know the importance of specific keywords

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, keyword, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import path
import re



with open(r'C:\Users\maxim\PycharmProjects\THESIS\data\santander2020_1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

dataset = [data]


tfIdfVectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, stop_words="english"
                                , lowercase=True,max_features=100,ngram_range=(1,3))
tfIdf = tfIdfVectorizer.fit_transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(tfIdf[0].T.todense(), index=tfIdfVectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["TF-IDF"])
df = df.sort_values('TF-IDF', ascending=False)




print (df.head(25))
```

The above code is what ive created to do a TF-IDF analysis on an annual report, however currently it is giving me the values of the most important words within the report. However, I only need the TFIDF values for the keywords
["digital","hardware","innovation","software","analytics","data","digitalisation","technology"], is there a way I can specify to only look for the tfidf values of these terms?

I'm very new to programming with little experience, I'm doing this for my thesis.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `tfIdf` as `tfIdf = tfIdfVectorizer.fit_transform(dataset)`.

So `tfIdf.toarray()` would be a 2-D array, where each row refers to a document and each element in the row refers to the TF-IDF score of the corresponding word. To know what word each element is representing, you could use the `.get_feature_names()` function which would print a list of words. Then you can use this information to create a mapping (dict) from words to scores, like this:

`wordScores = dict(zip(tfIdfVectorizer.get_feature_names(), tfIdf.toarray()[0]))`

Now suppose your document contains the word "digital" and you want to know its TF-IDF score, you could simply print the value of `wordScores["digital"]`.

Comment: After I add tfidfarray = tfIdf.toarray() and print it, I get a matrix of values, then when I create tfidfnames = tfidfarray.get_feature_names_out() and print that I get AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out', is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: I was suggesting "get_feature_names", not "get_feature_names_out". You could check this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.get_feature_names) and do update here if it works.

Comment: From what I understand, get_feature_names and get_feature_names_out is the same thing, and the former is being deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. tfidfarray is the ndarray version of tfIdf. It does not have any get_feature_names_out() method. You should be calling "tfIdfVectorizer.get_feature_names_out()" instead of "tfidfarray.get_feature_names_out()". Please refer to the original answer, there I have clearly mentioned usage of tfIdf, tfIdf.toarray() and tfIdfVectorizer. That should help avoid any confusion.